# GCP App Engine flex (GAE): Error when deploying

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

When deploying using `gcloud app deploy` I get the following error:

> Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy gcp

I contacted GCP Support and they told me the same thing I had read in other threads:

> the error you are referring to may be related to the Compute Engine “In-Use IP Addresses” Quota limit. You can view your current quota limit information by accessing from your GCP menu “IAM & Admin > Quotas”.

I checked the "In-Use IP Addresses" and it doesn't seem like I have a problem with quotas:

[image: My current quota image]

Looking for the error, I found that in the Activity tab, when deploying, I get an error. Apparently , when App Engine is trying to delete a VM, the process starts to loop trying to delete it. You can see the error:

[image: here]

(I intentionally covered the project ID)

Edit: It seem like the problem is only with southamerica-east1. I created a new project in southamerica-east1 but I kept getting the same error, so then I created a new project with the App Engine in us-west2 and worked like a charm (I used the same application and app.yaml). I wonder if the problem is GCP southamerica-east1 or a unknown bad configuration by my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we didn't find a real solution so we moved all our services from Brazil to US-2. I'm not sure if the Region is the problem, but there in US-2 all works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/73583699.  It does mentioned the "in-use IP Address" quota, but many people have posted in recent days (Nov 2018) indicating that they are seeing the error and have verified that they have not hit their quota.

Unfortunately, no solution has been posted and there hasn't been any recent comment from the devs.

Comment: I'm not sure it that is the same exact error that we faced. We ending changing from Brazil to US-2 and that worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

First, our apologies that you’ve experienced this issue. Be assured that we are aware of the situation and the team works hard to resolve it.

Our goal is to make sure that there are available resources in all zones. This
type of issue is rare. When a situation like this occurs, or is about to
occur, our team is notified immediately and the issue is investigated.

We recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or
regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. Please review our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps)
which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google
Cloud Platform.

For the time being, you can try relaxing your requirements (e.g. requesting a smaller instance or one with fewer resources) or removing the external IP requirement.
If that proves not to be enough, you can try deploying your application to another [region](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/)

Again, we want to offer our sincerest apologies.

Thanks for understanding.